# Jquery: call a function automatically

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to call a jquery function in each 10 Minuit in my MVC project.

```
setInterval(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                cache: false,
                url: "/Home/dwnld_all",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        }, 600000);
```

This is my code. But in this, it doesn't work when the control go to next page.  Is there any jquery code for this?

Comment: when you say "control go to next page" do you mean when the page redirects?

Comment: yes. when the page redirect is occurred then "setInterval" doesn't work.

Comment: maybe store the time of the interval in local storage and read it when page loads

Comment: keep this code in your layout page......

Comment: you are redirecting back to the same page? or you have this code within two different pages?

Answer (score 0):

Your js is limited to the current page. It can't by default be accessed across reloaded pages. You will need to take the help of some server side code. Something like this:

```
// Your controller action that you will be redirecting to
public ActionResult MyAction(int pendingInterval){
    ViewBag.Pending = pendingInterval;
    return View();
}
```

You can now modify your js to the following:

```
function keepRunning() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            url: "/Home/dwnld_all",
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
 }
```

In your view page you can have the following code to initially run the `keepRunning` function

```
setTimeout(function(){
    keepRunning() // run initially for the ending time
    setInterval(keepRunning, 600000);
}, @ViewBag.Pending);
```

Now when you redirect your page, you will have to pass your remaining time as well to the url.